# Check if FrameworkElement does have Border

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, frameworkelement

I got a `FrameworkElement` within the eventhandler of a class. Is there a possibility to check if this `FrameworkElement` is an element that has a borderthickness/borderbrush property ?

Like

```
var element = myframeworkelement as IHasBorder;
element.borderthickness = new Thickness(1,2,3,4);
```

Does something like this exist ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties `BorderThickness` and `BorderBrush` are defined in the `Control` class.

So you can try to cast your `FrameworkElement` to `Control`, and if that works, set the properties:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var pnl = new StackPanel();
        this.Content = pnl;

        var button = new Button();
        button.Content = "Hi";

        pnl.Children.Add(button);

        SetBorder(button);
    }

    public void SetBorder(FrameworkElement fe)
    {
        var borderControl = fe as Control;

        if (borderControl != null)
        {
            borderControl.BorderThickness = new Thickness(10);
            borderControl.BorderBrush = Brushes.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah did that. Thought there are further opportunities. Thanks for your confirmation